iOS simulator takes extremely long time to boot on Xcode16
Our org's CI pipeline is experiencing extremely long build time due to iOS simulators takes a long time to boot (15+ minutes)
This problem persist in all Xcode16 versions including the most recent Xcode16.2 RC.
We are using iPhone 14 with iOS 18.2
Anyone else experiencing the same thing? If so, any workaround out there?
